# How to delete duplicate path aliases?

Tags: database, path-aliases

Duplicate path aliases are seen as rows in the `path_alias` table with identical `path` and `alias` columns.

Due to old bugs in pathauto and other reasons, like buggy custom code, it is possible to have duplicate rows in the `path_alias` table. This can make the `path_alias` enormous for large sites.

Duplicate path aliases serve no purpose whatsoever. You only need one of each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are many duplicates, use the queue system to delete them gradually. Start by enqueuing identified duplicates in an update hook:

```php
// file: my_module.install
/**
 * Enqueue duplicate path aliases for cleanup.
 */
function my_module_update_10001() {
  $query = \Drupal::database()->select('path_alias', 'pa')
    ->fields('pa', ['alias']);
  $query->addExpression('count(alias)');
  $query->groupBy('alias');
  $query->having('COUNT(alias) >= :matches', [':matches' => 2]);
  $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
  \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice('Enqueuing duplicate path aliases for cleanup');
  foreach ($results as $alias) {
    $queue = \Drupal::queue('my_module_delete_duplicate_path_aliases');
    $queue->createItem($alias);
  }
  return t('Update 10001 completed successfully.');
}
```

Add the `my_module_delete_duplicate_path_aliases` queue runner to do the work:

```php
<?php
// file: src/Plugin/QueueWorker/DeleteDuplicatePathAliases.php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\QueueWorker;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Queue\QueueWorkerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Deletes duplicate path aliases.
 *
 * @QueueWorker(
 *   id = "my_module_delete_duplicate_path_aliases",
 *   title = @Translation("Delete duplicate path aliases"),
 *   cron = {"time" = 30}
 * )
 */
class DeleteDuplicatePathAliases extends QueueWorkerBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  final public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    private LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger,
    private EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager,
  ) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('logger.factory'),
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processItem($data) {
    $alias = (string) $data;
    $query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('path_alias')->getQuery();
    $entity_ids = $query
      ->accessCheck(FALSE)
      ->condition('alias', $alias)
      ->sort('id', 'DESC')
      ->execute();

    /** @var \Drupal\path_alias\Entity\PathAlias[] $entities */
    $entities = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('path_alias')->loadMultiple($entity_ids);

    $count = 0;
    // Keep the newest unique aliases by language and path, and delete the rest.
    $seen = [];
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
      if (isset($seen[$entity->language()->getId()][$entity->getPath()])) {
        $entity->delete();
        $count++;
      }
      $seen[$entity->language()->getId()][$entity->getPath()] = TRUE;
    }
    $this->logger->get('my_module')->notice('Deleted ' . $count . ' duplicate path aliases for ' . $alias);
  }

}
```